# Can I split data into 2 collections in Mongo DB and access the same in SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Mongo DB as Database for my springboot application.

I wanted to split the data into 2 collections -primary and auxillary just like how we do it in sql- priamary and secondary table.

Can i do the above and use them in my Springboot application??

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot + Spring data mongo supports multiple collections out of the box.

Just create your POJOs and add the `@Document` annotation.

You can then define Repository classes (extends MongoRepository) that are then bound to each collection.
Use them to perform nearly any actions on the data.

If you want the data to be in multiple databases, that is also possible, just a bit more complicated.

Comment: i want data to be in multiple collections but bound to one primary collections -its like one to one relationship.can this be achieved?

Comment: Mongo is not a relational database, so while you can define "relationships" and enforce them in your service via code, Mongo will not assist you i.e. no cascaded deletes, no referential integrity.